# Is credit the principal force behind the business cycle, as claimed on a Dalio youtube video?

Tags: economics

The following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHe0bXAIuk0 seems to argue that credit is the principal force behind the business cycle, as far as I cal tell.

Is this considered to be a established truth?

Comment: It's correct as far as it goes, but doesn't/can't take human emotion, external forces and politics into account.  For example, Dalio's nice overlapping cycles couldn't have foreseen 9/11 and the oil price shocks of the 1970s.